# SharePoint Application Pool Restart - Effects?

Tags: sharepoint, pool

We have SharePoint 2007, running II6...

Currently we have a problem with a troublesome webpart which is being investigated by the developers.

Basically it crashes frequently and an App Pool restart of the main SharePoint site fixes this (until it breaks again).

When we restart the app pool it takes SharePoint down for 30 secs or so, but what I dont know is...

- What effects does recycling the app pool have on users using SharePoint? Any (above its un-availability for 30 ish seconds
- Could recycling the app pool often cause any problems?
- Im guessing its not recommended?

I know we should take the webpart out altogether until its fixed, but its not feasible unfortunately, the business says its stays.

Any info would be great,

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A restart of an Application Pool enforces the w3wp process to be restarted. As you can see in your taskmanager you've one w3wp instance per Application Pool.

The first hit after the app pool restart always took long because each assembly have to be loaded and the first hit compilation for each aspx will occur.

The drawnback is, that while terminating the AppPool it's possible to lose data which are currently being transferred to the server. 
Therefor the restart commando has a noforce flag which blocks the process from being terminated until all requests are processed.

Answer (score 1):

As you surmise, it is less than ideal and the crashing application pool could certainly cause other users with inflight interactions with SharePoint to be aborted.